# Rename size variant titles in shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically rename the size variants "Small" "Medium" "large" "x-large" "xx-large" "xxx-large", to "S" "M" "L" "XL "XXL" .. etc.

The reason why I want to rename the size variants is because of the amount of extra space that is being taken up.

I am creating products from an app that doesn't let me change the name of the size variants prior to creating the products in shopify. It wouldn't make sense to manually go and change each product's variant titles because it's not time efficient.

I'm thinking the best way to do this is by using Javascript, but I don't know exactly how to go about doing this so it doesn't break anything.

Here is an example of the HTML source code of the Medium size variant.

```
<div data-value="Medium" class="swatch-element medium-swatch available"> <label for="swatch-1-medium-286472667159">
            Medium <span class="crossed-out"></span></label></div>
```

---

Liquid Source for the swatches.

```
    <div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="{{ option_index }}">
  <div class="option_title">{{ swatch }}</div>
  {% assign values = '' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign value = variant.options[option_index] %}
    {% unless values contains value %}
      {% assign values = values | join: ',' %}
      {% assign values = values | append: ',' | append: value %}
      {% assign values = values | split: ',' %}

      <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}-{{ product.id }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if forloop.first %} checked{% endif %} />
      <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" class="swatch-element {% if is_color %}color {% endif %}{{ value | handle }}-swatch {% if variant.available %}available{% else %}soldout{% endif %}">
        {% if is_color %}
          <div class="tooltip">{{ value }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if is_color %}
          <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}-{{ product.id }}" style="background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | asset_img_url: '50x' }}); background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }};">
            <span class="crossed-out"></span>
          </label>
        {% else %}
          <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}-{{ product.id }}">
            {{ value }}
            <span class="crossed-out"></span>
          </label>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the workaround, I can suggest you this way:

1. Export products from Shopify in plain CSV
2. Open CSV file in excel
3. Rename all size variants in excel with "find and replace"
4. Import again into Shopify (make sure, you selected `Overwrite existing products that have the same handle`)